# check pass boolean function

Tags: python, function, boolean

This is my code which and it asks a user to enter a password string and checks for any repeated elements.The thing is I didn't understand the code and why they set a `unique_element` to an empty string.And what does `unique+=password[i]` do,why is `i` in  `[]` in this brackets?

```
def check_pass():     
    password= raw_input('Enter a password:')
    unique_element = ''
    for i in range (len(password)):
        if len(unique_element) == 0:
            unique_element += password [i]     
        else:
            not_unique = True
            for j in range (len(unique_element)):
                if unique_element[j] == password[i]:
                    not_unique = False
            if not_unique:
                unique_element += password[i]
    return unique_element == password
print check_pass()
```

Comment: you are looping through the password..`for i in range (len(password)):` and accessing it..

Comment: This is a very inefficient way to check for unique characters. `def check_pass(): password = input('Enter a password:') ; return len(password) == len(set(password))`

Comment: Also weird that it is your code and you don't understand it...

Comment: Your ask very basic questions. I think you should read the language documentation. 
Read about datatypes, loops and array would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining the Code above may be a little tedious. Suffice it to say that if your intention is to check if a given String [`password`] contains any duplicate character, you might do that without the need for any loops - which (in this case) is likely unnecessary. Here's how:

```
def pass_has_unique_characters():
    # CAPTURE THE ENTERED CHARACTERS
    password        = input('Enter a password:')
    # SETS CANNOT HAVE DUPLICATES SO WE CAST THE STRING (password) TO A SET
    st_password     = set(password)
    # NOW WE CHECK THE LENGTHS OF BOTH: password AND st_password
    # IF BOTH HAVE THE SAME LENGTH, THEN THE PASS HAS UNIQUE CHARACTERS, 
    # RETURN [True] ... OTHERWISE RETURN [False]
    return (True if len(st_password) == len(password) else False)


print(pass_has_unique_characters())
```

Comment: can u explain how he did with loops,because i dont know about set shortcut